# How to achieve the following code using List Comprehensions?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How to achieve the following code using List Comprehensions?

```
for r in range(row):
    for c in range(column):
        print [r,c]
```

Thx

Comment: It should be a straight forward nested list-comp, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: @mgilson, I need it to avoid writting row*column times the same line of code: axes[i, j].axis('off') . Note: axis('off') comes from matplotlib.subplot

Comment: A list comprehension won't help with that, it's not more or less recursive than a simple `for`.

Comment: From the first version of your question I think you are turning the axis off for an array of matplotlib subplots. Therefore, you can do something like `[ax.axis('off') for ax in axes.flatten()]`

Comment: @DavidG Does `axis('off')` return a value which you might want to use later? If not, don't use a list comprehension…

Comment: @DavidG,It works. Thx you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My list comprehension suggestion in the comments should probably not be used as this will indeed fill up a list with `None`s as others have pointed out.

Seeing the extra code in the answer you provided shows that a for loop is probably the way to go and is *much* more readable IMO:

So replace your list comprehension:

```
plot_it = [ ( ax.imshow(img[1], cmap='gray'), ax.set_title(img[0], fontsize=15), ax.axis('off') )
            for ax, img in zip(axes.flatten(), list_title_image)]
```

with:

```
for ax, img in zip(axes.flatten(), list_title_image):
    ax.imshow(img[1], cmap='gray')
    ax.set_title(img[0], fontsize=15)
    ax.axis('off')
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
[[print([r,c]) for c in range(column)] for r in range(row)]
```

Thank you mgilson. Didn't drink enough coffee and forget how to say 'nested' in English and in my native language :)

**UPDATE:**
I will stick with DavidG's solution:

```
 [ax.axis('off') for ax in axes.flatten()]
```

Thx to this solution, I can reduce the following code:

```
# Plot the result
row, column = [3, 2]
figure, axes = plt.subplots(row, column, figsize=(15, 10))
figure.tight_layout()

axes[0,0].imshow(image)
axes[0,0].set_title('Original Image', fontsize=15)
axes[0,0].axis('off')

axes[0,1].imshow(img_solution, cmap='gray')
axes[0,1].set_title('Expected result', fontsize=15)
axes[0,1].axis('off')

axes[1,0].imshow(gradx, cmap='gray')
axes[1,0].set_title('gradx', fontsize=15)
axes[1,0].axis('off')

axes[1,1].imshow(grady, cmap='gray')
axes[1,1].set_title('grady', fontsize=15)
axes[1,1].axis('off')

axes[2,0].imshow(mag_binary, cmap='gray')
axes[2,0].set_title('mag_binary', fontsize=15)
axes[2,0].axis('off')

axes[2,1].imshow(dir_binary, cmap='gray')
axes[2,1].set_title('dir_binary', fontsize=15)
axes[2,1].axis('off')
```

By these few lines:

```
# Plot the result
row, column = [3, 2]
figure, axes = plt.subplots(row, column, figsize=(15, 10))
figure.tight_layout()
list_title_image = [['Original Image',image],
                    ['Expected result', img_solution],
                    ['gradx', gradx],
                    ['grady', grady],
                    ['mag_binary', mag_binary],
                    ['dir_binary', dir_binary] ]

plot_it = [ ( ax.imshow(img[1], cmap='gray'), ax.set_title(img[0], fontsize=15), ax.axis('off') ) 
            for ax, img in zip(axes.flatten(), list_title_image)]
```

Where ax.axis('off') is an array of matplotlib subplots

Comment: If this is what you want, it's good, but I wonder why you want a list filled with None just for syntactic variation. Does it need to be on one line only?

Comment: Nope. It is only to reduce the number of lines to make the code more readable.

Comment: But you're consuming much more memory in the process for lists full of `None`s. Don't do it. List comprehensions yield a value. A `for` loop doesn't. Write what you mean. There's no shortage of lines.